# Should i enable Cloudflare for A records for my nameservers

Tags: cloudflare

I am using Cloudflare, and my domain is using their nameservers olga and duke.
I have A records for ns1.mydomain.com and ns2.mydomain.com and that is only thing which is revealing my real IP address, because i can not force clients to use CloudFlare. So I host their DNS.

If I enable CloudFlare for my NS1 & NS2 A records, will everything continue to work well?
Notice: NS1 and NS2 at registrar are will still be pointing to real IP address.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Cloudflare you need to choose one of the following configurations:

- Change your name servers at the registrar and use in Full mode,
- Use via a hosting partner, or
- Upgrade to BIZ and use a CNAME setup

[Cloudflare Knowledge Base Article](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/203685674-What-are-the-partner-Cloudflare-setup-options-Full-DNS-vs-CNAME-)

Comment: U do not understand.
I am certifed hosting parnter, i have mysite.com and i am using cloudflare with full mode using their dns. But my clients do not (at least not all of them) some full some through plugin i installed, others use ns1.mydomain.com ns2.mydomain.
My questions was can i enable cloudflare for a records of ns1 and ns2 because they are only thing revealing my real ip address.
I hope you understand now

Comment: In that case this is probably something that is best handled by customer support.  Please email your details to support[at]cloudflare[dot]com

Answer (score 0):

Whilst Cloudflare can host the DNS records for your host - it will not proxy DNS records; Cloudflare will only proxy HTTP and HTTPS traffic.

If you wish to proxy DNS traffic you can use Cloudflare's [Virtual DNS](https://www.cloudflare.com/dns/virtual-dns/) product. This acts as a firewall for your existing DNS infrastructure.

Comment: I didn't said that.
I said i am using FULL DNS which means mydomain.com has cloudflare DUKE and OLGA nameservers as i already TOLD in my main question.
Everything is going through cloudflare network except my nameservers which are

Ns1.mysite.com
ns2.mysite.com
Why?
Because i have clients who are using my nameservers (listed above) so I host their DNS.
If I enable cloudflare for NS1 and NS2 will everything continue to work fine, that was my question

Comment: Ordinarily Cloudflare will not proxy DNS traffic. If this is something you want to do - please review Cloudflare's Virtual DNS offering: https://www.cloudflare.com/dns/virtual-dns/